# users/roles/permissions implementaion using Yii framework

Tags: yii, user-permissions, user-roles

I want to implement a custom CMS using Yii framework.

As any CMS I need to be able to:

- Create Users
- Create Roles (Groups)
- Assign users to Roles/Groups
- Give roles Edit/Delete/Manage permission to other parts(modules) of the site like creating pages,menu,...

But I have no idea about implementing those.

Would you give me some ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to implement it! There is a fantastic extension that's very good at rights management: The [Rights Extension for Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/).

This extension utilizes Yii's built-in Database Authorization Manager (CDbAuthManager) to provide a web interface for advanced access control.

**Features**

- User interface optimized for usability Role, task and operation
- Management View displaying each role's assigned tasks and operations
- Assigning authorization items to users Sorting of authorization items by dragging and dropping
- Installer for easy and quick set up
- Authorization item generation Controller filter for checking access
- Support for business rules (and data) Runtime caching to increase
- Performance Internationalization (I18N) Cross-browser and
- Cross-database compatibility Easy to extend

Comment: I've tried to install it from the Yii wiki instructions.but It gives me the superuser error (403 error). I have logged in with admin account.